# The sequence of setting up keystone v3?

Tags: openstack, keystone

I would like to set up keystone V3. After studying the reference from the Internet, some confused me.

[This one](http://www.florentflament.com/blog/setting-keystone-v3-domains.html) creates an admin domain to v3 endpoint with default v2 policy.json first and then changes policy.json.

[Another one](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/how-switch-keystone-v20-v3) changes policy.json and modifies endpoint to v3 in database first.

Which one should I follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are doing the same thing but as you note, in a different order. The order doesn't matter as long as both the database and policy.json are updated. However you can see from the domains discussion that you may not get all the features in the dashboard for example with Identity v3. You can read more about policy.json in http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/identity-service-api-protection-with-role-based-access-control.html.

Comment: Thank a lot. I finished the setup. 1) Change DB, 2) create cloud_admin and admin domain with old policy and 3) replace policy.json to v3.